# Having problems importing maven bom in gradle

Tags: gradle, maven-bom

I’m using

implementation org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.3.RELEASE

to import a maven bom file however when the pom file is generated for the artifact this gets included in the file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

now if I use this dependency in a maven project it fails since it is looking for a jar artifact not a pom
, is this a bug how gradle handles pom files from maven?

Comment: What have you searched, what have you checked, post your code where you get the error lets see if we can help you out.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what code you want me post here... the piece of pom file I posted here is generated by Gradle... but spring-boot-dependencies it supposed to be a pom file nor a jar file as it is being generated and as I mentioned I'm using the implementation in my gradle file. The problem here is that gradle genrates the dependency in the pom file as a jar artifact when in fact is just a bom